# First time buyer of Mooney with some questions

Tags: aircraft-purchase, mooney-m20

I am a private pilot, with 120 hours, working on my Instrument rating, will be a first time buyer. I am interested in getting Mooney M20C for time buildup and cross country. I like them for being efficient and fast. I have few questions.

1. How much down payment should I have? Most financial institution's websites shows its 15% but when I called one of them today they told me its 20-25% with rate being around 5.5%-6.0%.
2. How much liquid asset is required for financing?
3. Can you recommend any banks/financial institutions for financing?
4. What type of insurance is required by the law if the only purpose of the plane is pleasure under Part 91.
5. I saw someone selling a share of a Mooney at my local airport but he told me that I can't get insured if I don't have at least 100 hours of retractable gear time. He wasn't too helpful in explaining further. Is that the case with all the insurances or some will insure me with high premiums?

Comment: Good questions, although I'm not sure they're a good fit for this site's format (see the [tour] for more information on how the site works). #1-3 and #5 are mostly opinion-based. Or at least, there could be very different answers for different people. The answer to #4 is "none", but there are situations where you might still have to get it, e.g. you rent a hangar and the hangar owner requires you to have insurance. You might get a better response in a forum, especially [mooneyspace.com](https://mooneyspace.com/).

Comment: For #4, none required by law, but your lender will certainly require some. Answers to #1, #2 and #5 will vary by lender. #3 is opinion-based.

Comment: And for #5, it’s not that you can’t get insured with less, but the other partners probably won’t like the rates. My club only requires 10-20 hours of retract time, but the insurance bill is split 80 ways, so it’s not that bad per person.

Answer (score 2):

Ill answer #5 since that is on topic here. The others questions are mostly about personal finance and not aviation.

Insurance companies can require what ever they deem applicable for their own policies. 100 hours is high but not unreasonable, for the average pilot thats about a year worth of flying.

The variable you are missing here is the specific Mooney since there are a lot of M20 variants that will have wildly different premiums. About a year after my PPL I got serious about the possibility of buying a Mooney M20C or E and had no issue getting reasonable insurance quotes with 0 hours of retract time. The quotes were of course contingent on me finishing my complex endorsement.

The issue here is that the owner already *has* insurance so you are at the mercy of what the policy currently says. The other pilot may also be using it as an excuse to not sell the shares to a low time pilot.

I'd say not much further explanation is needed. Any time the ownership is group based, be it a [few people](https://www.aopa.org/go-fly/aircraft-and-ownership/buying-an-aircraft/pilots-guide-to-co-ownership) who go in on a plane or [a club](https://youcanfly.aopa.org/flying-clubs) there are usually insurance minimums to be a "member" of the organization.